# How to print to a serial printer (e.g. Epson TM-U210) from .NET?

Tags: c#, printing, epson

Please tell me how to print invoice using Epson TM-U210 printer using C#. I can print invoice using normal USB printer such as HP inkjet printers. I used

```
printDocument1.Print();
```

command to print. But Epson printer is serial port printer. There for is there any need of using port command and use any byte to write? Please at least guide me. I don't have any idea to where to start. Thank you so much

Comment: there are some sdk's also for .net for these kinds of printers here. That would be a good place to start. https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=39

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to solutions like this, I often avoid the actual communications layer.  I'd mock up the output that you want to to send and fire off to the local printer queue that you've already created on the local system.  This let's Windows handle the communication via the COM port and will handle all the low level items such as taking the print queue offline if the printer is off etc.

Take a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

I typically do this for USB printers too so I don't have to keep track of what USB port the printer is on and if it's out of paper then Windows handles the queuing etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But many developer use POS.Net for printing invoice. I dont know what is the advantage of using them. If there any guide about those things, please tel me. Thank you again for your reply.